# How to find this Fourier Transform without the use of integration?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

If I have $\mathcal{F}(f(t))=F(\omega)$ with $$f(t)= \begin{cases} 1, & 0 \leq t < \pi\\ -1,&- \pi \leq t <0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I have found

$$F(\omega)= \begin{cases} \frac{2i}{\omega}(\cos(\omega \pi)-1) & \omega \neq 0 \\ 0 & \omega = 0 \end{cases}$$

I do not know how to find a $g(t)=f(t)\sin(\alpha t)$ without the use of integration.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you use the time shift properties of theFourier Transform?

Comment: Yes, you can use the time shift properties, and probably this is what the person asking the question intended. If $$g(t) = \begin{cases}1, & -\pi/2 < t < \pi/2 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \\ \end{cases}$$ then $f(t) = g(t - \pi/2) - g(t + \pi/2)$. The Fourier transform of $g$ is of the form $\sin(\omega)/\omega$, with scale factors depending on which definition of the Fourier transform you use.

Answer (score 2):

**General Fourier Transform, by formal definition:**
$$
\mathcal{F}_{(a,b)}(f(t)) = \sqrt{\dfrac{|b|}{(2\pi)^{1-a}}} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t)e^{i b \omega t} dt
$$
As generally known, the pair of values $(a,b)$ are chosen depending on the context of use of the Fourier transform:

- $(0,+1)$: *Default; Modern Physics.*
- $(+1,-1)$: *Pure Mathematics; Systems Engineering*
- $(-1,+1)$: *Classical Physics*
- $(0,-2\pi)$: *Signal Processing*

I will assume you are using the Fourier transform in a context of pure mathematics or systems engineering. Thus:
$$
\mathcal{F}_{(+1,-1)}(f(t)) = \mathcal{F}(f(t)) = F(\omega) \quad\Rightarrow\quad F(\omega)= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t)e^{-i \omega t} dt
$$

---

**Since the Fourier transform is defined by an integral, it's impossible to evaluate the fourier transform without the use of integration.** Instead of it, you can build a table of Fourier transforms to solve your problem, with the appropriate functions. The question now is...

***What are the appropriate functions to build a table of Fourier transforms useful?***

You should choose your table of transforms according to the most common functions in your work context. It's something intuitive. There isn't much science in it.

**The real trick is to build that table of transforms, multiplying each function by the unit step function.** The reason for doing this is very interesting: you can build any function at defined intervals with known functions, with the combination of those known functions multiplied by the unit step function (shifted in time and/or multiplied by a factor, if necessary).

*Note: I will use the following notation to simplify fourier transform.*
$$
\mathcal{F}(f(t)) = F(\omega) \quad \Leftrightarrow\quad f(t) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} F(\omega)
$$
*And remember these properties of the Fourier transform:*
$$
\begin{align}
\mbox{Shifted i}&\mbox{n Time} & f(t\pm a) &\xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} F(\omega) e^{\pm ia\omega} \\
\mbox{Superposition}&\mbox{ Principle} & af_1(t) + bf_2(t)&\xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} aF_1(\omega) + bF_2(\omega)
\end{align}
$$

---

**First example:** with unit step function, where $\delta(\omega)$ is the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) (proof [here](http://bueler.github.io/M611F05/M611heaviside.pdf)):
$$
u(t) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} 1, & t > 0 \\ 0, & t < 0 \end{matrix} \right. \quad \Rightarrow \quad u(t) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} \dfrac{1}{i\omega} + \pi\delta(\omega) = U(\omega)
$$
Defining $f_1(t)$ using the unit step function, *sweeping* from left to right:
$$
f_1(t) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} +1, & 0 < t < +\pi \\ -1, & -\pi < t < 0, \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{matrix} \right. \quad \Rightarrow \quad f_1(t) = -u(t+\pi)  +2u(t) -u(t-\pi)
$$
Applying Fourier transform and its properties (and [exp form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) of $\cos(\pi\omega)$):
$$
\begin{align}
f_1(t) &\xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} -U(\omega)e^{i\pi\omega} + 2 U(\omega) - U(\omega)e^{-i\pi\omega} \\
f_1(t) &\xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} - \left( \dfrac{1}{i\omega} + \pi\delta(\omega)\right)e^{i\pi\omega} + 2 \left(\dfrac{1}{i\omega} + \pi\delta(\omega)\right) - \left( \dfrac{1}{i\omega} + \pi\delta(\omega)\right)e^{-i\pi\omega} \\
f_1(t) &\xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} \dfrac{2i}{\omega} \left(\cos(\pi\omega) - 1\right) \\
\end{align}
$$
Since:
$$
\lim\limits_{\omega\to 0} 2\pi\delta(\omega) -\left(\pi\delta(\omega)e^{i\pi\omega} + \pi\delta(\omega)e^{-i\pi\omega} \right) = \lim\limits_{\omega\to 0} 2\pi\delta(\omega)\left( 1-\cos(\pi\omega) \right) = 0\\
\therefore\quad \forall\omega\in\mathbb{R}:\quad 2\pi\delta(\omega) -\left(\pi\delta(\omega)e^{i\pi\omega} + \pi\delta(\omega)e^{-i\pi\omega} \right) = 0
$$

---

**Second example:** integrate and include in your table of Fourier transform:
$$
\begin{align}
\forall a\in\mathbb{R}:&
&
e^{-a t}u(t) &\xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} \dfrac{1}{a+\omega i} = E_{(a)}(\omega)
& 
e^{-ia t}u(t) &\xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} \dfrac{1}{ai+\omega i} + \pi\delta(\omega + a) = E_{ia}(\omega)
& &
\end{align} 
$$
$$
\therefore \quad E_{ia}(\omega) = E_{(ia)}(\omega) + \pi\delta(\omega + a)
$$
Defining $f_2(t)$:
$$
f_2(t) = f_1(t)\sin(\alpha t) = -u(t+\pi)\sin(\alpha t)  +2u(t)\sin(\alpha t) -u(t-\pi)\sin(\alpha t)
$$
Where it's convenient to define (using [exp form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) of $\sin(\alpha t)$):
$$
\begin{align} 
g(t) &= u(t+a)\sin(\alpha t) \\
&= \dfrac{i}{2}e^{-i\alpha t}u(t+a) - \dfrac{i}{2}e^{i\alpha t}u(t+a) \\
\therefore\quad g(t-a)&= \dfrac{i}{2}e^{-i\alpha t}u(t) - \dfrac{i}{2}e^{i\alpha t}u(t) \\
&= \dfrac{ie^{ia \alpha}}{2}e^{-i\alpha t}u(t) - \dfrac{ie^{-ia \alpha}}{2}e^{i\alpha t}u(t) \\
\end{align} 
$$
Applying Fourier transform and its properties:
$$
\begin{align} 
g(t-a) &\xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} \dfrac{i}{2}e^{ia \alpha}E_{+ia}(\omega) - \dfrac{i}{2}e^{-ia \alpha}E_{-ia}(\omega) \\
\therefore \quad g(t) &\xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} \dfrac{i}{2}e^{ia (\alpha+\omega)}E_{+ia}(\omega) - \dfrac{i}{2}e^{-ia (\alpha-\omega)}E_{-ia}(\omega) = G_{a}(\omega)
\end{align}
$$
Thus:
$$
u(t+a)\sin(\alpha t) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} G_{a}(\omega)
$$
And finally:
$$
\begin{align}
f_2(t) &\xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} -G_{-\pi}(\omega) + 2G_{0}(\omega) - G_{+\pi}(\omega) \\
f_2(t) &\xrightarrow{\mathcal{F}} \dfrac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2 - \omega^2} - \dfrac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2 - \omega^2} \cos(\pi\alpha)\cos(\pi\omega) - \dfrac{2\omega}{\alpha^2 - \omega^2} \sin(\pi\alpha)\sin(\pi\omega)
\end{align}
$$
I leave to you the verification of this solution as homework (use [angle sum and difference identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities))

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the integrals against the $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms separately. Those with $\cos$ vanish because your function is odd. The coefficient of the first $\sin$ term is
$$
          2\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x)dx
$$
The only terms that survive are those involving
$$
      \sin(x),\sin(3x),\sin(5x),\sin(7x),\cdots
$$
You end up with
$$
       2\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin((2n+1)x)dx
        = 2\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/(2n+1)}\sin((2n+1)x)dx
$$
The integral over $\sin((2n+1)x$ over $[0,\pi]$ cancels except for $\int_{0}^{\pi/(2n+1)}\sin((2n+1)x)dx$ which is the same as the area under $\sin(x)$ on $[0,\pi]$, but scaled by $\frac{1}{2n+1}$. So the above equals
$$
          \frac{1}{2n+1}2\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x)dx.
$$
So the Fourier series is
$$
      \left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2k+1}\sin((2k+1)x)\right]\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x')dx'.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since

$$\mathcal{F} \left( \sin (\alpha t) \right) = i \pi \left( \delta (\omega + \alpha) - \delta (\omega - \alpha) \right)$$

and multiplication in the time domain is equivalent to convolution in the frequency domain, we have

$$G (\omega) = i \pi F (\omega + \alpha) - i \pi F (\omega - \alpha)$$